# AdRequest not resolved, and marked with RED,But the app works fine

Tags: android, admob, adview

I am facing strange problem.

```
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
```

in above lines the classes `AdRequest` and `AdView` marked RED and the IDE tells: `Cannot resolve symbol!`
But when I run the application on my device every thing run OK. No compiler errors and I see Ads on my device.
Following are my dependencies.

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
compile files('src/main/java/nineoldandroid.jar')
compile files('android.jar')
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.4.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.4.0'

compile files('httpclient-4.5.2.jar')
compile files('httpcore-4.4.4.jar')
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:9.4.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

And xml file

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-*******"
    android:layout_above="@+id/adView2"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:background="#000000" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the Error: I am using:

```
 compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.4.0'
```

I just replace with:

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:9.6.0'
```